# extract info from modal on submit python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i am trying to extract info from a div when the item is summited this is the site https://url/en/mybill/

[image]

when you click on check my bills the modal opens up and once you insert a number some text is outputted in a div generated called `formstatus`
[image]

i would like to extract in text inside that div but unable to this is what i have so far for my code

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://waterauthority.com.fj/en/mybill/")
meter_id = wd.find_element_by_id("colour")
meter_id.send_keys('123') 
wd.find_element_by_name("colour").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
delay = 10
try:
  myElem = WebDriverWait(wd, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formstatus')))  
  print(myElem)
except TimeoutException:
  print ("No work")
```

i keep getting the output as `no work`
any help would be appreciated please note i am very new to this library

run the code online-

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FZ52_8DMRsQv2iseJlsQoHiXA97jLh2v?usp=sharing
make sure to run the first block first before running the code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below css selector :

```
div[id='formstatus']
```

**code :**

```
try:
  myElem = WebDriverWait(wd, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id='formstatus']")))  
  print(myElem.text)
except TimeoutException:
  print ("No work")
```

**update 1 :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://waterauthority.com.fj/en/mybill/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='close']//*[local-name()='svg']"))).click()
    print("found and clicked")
except:
    pass

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Check My Bill')]"))).click()
meter_id = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='colour']")))
meter_id.send_keys('123')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "save"))).click()
delay = 10
try:
  myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id='formstatus']")))
  print(myElem.text)
except TimeoutException:
  print ("No work")
```

Comment: no it does not work i have updated my code and added a online code you can have a look

Comment: you just want to extract this right `No record found. Please enter a valid bill number.` ? what was the error when you used the above css selector ?

Comment: i get a timeoutexception

Comment: and you were expecting `No record found. Please enter a valid bill number.` ? are you using pycharm ?

Comment: yes i was expecting that or if i enter a valid number then some other text would show up

Comment: i get a timeout exception in this line `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Check My Bill')]"))).click()`

Comment: updated again, it works fine on my pycharm, I have not tried this in colab.

Comment: this code does work, but it does not work in colab any reason as to why?

Comment: that's headless, I need to check that

Comment: actually when i add the chrome options it also does not work for pycharm

Comment: yes, even it did not work in headless mode, I will spend some time on this

Comment: i actually found a work around for this without using selenium

Comment: but finding a solution for headless would be great for future use

Comment: in headless I am able to click on check my cibil button using `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Check My Bill"))).click()` line. Only last line is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

First you need to click on "Check My Bill" button - I can't see that in your code.
Then send keys to "colour" input element.
And then extract the result text.

```
wd.get("https://waterauthority.com.fj/en/mybill/")
WebDriverWait(wd, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'header .jet-popup-target'))).click
meter_id = WebDriverWait(wd, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'colour')))
meter_id.send_keys('123')
meter_id.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
result_element = WebDriverWait(wd, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formstatus')))
print(result_element.text)
```

Comment: does not work :( , updated my code for a online copy

Comment: @laiakini please check the updated answer

Comment: i didnt click coz its a modal isnt it just hidden in html ?

Comment: and that code doesnt work as well please check this 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FZ52_8DMRsQv2iseJlsQoHiXA97jLh2v?usp=sharing